# How would I password protect a USB Thumb Drive?

Tags: disk-utility, encryption

I'm putting some sensitive information on a USB thumb drive and I'd like to password protect it so it can only be accessed with a password I set. I used to be able to Erase with **Mac OS Extended (Journaled, Encrypted)** from Disk Utilities but that doesn't seem to be an option anymore. Is there still a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to change the 'Scheme' drop-down to GUID Partition Map. I just fired up Disk Utility and the encrypted format seems to only be available when that is selected.